# How to store the value of document.getElementById("myNumber") in a variable and add an if-else statement

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>question 5</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="b0" onclick="start()">Start Game</button>
  <br>

  <img src="happy_fish.png" id="fish" onclick="mySore()">

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var image_tracker = 'happy';
    var image = document.getElementById('fish');
    image.style.display = "none";

    function change() {
      if (image_tracker == 'happy') {

        image.src = 'happy_fish.png';
        image_tracker = 'sad';
      } else {
        image.src = 'sad_fish.png';
        image_tracker = 'happy';
      }

    }
    var timer;

    function start() {
      image.style.display = "block";
      timer = setInterval('change();', 600);
    }

    function stop() {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }


    function mySore() {
      if (image_tracker == 'sad') {
        var x = document.getElementById("myNumber").stepUp();
        if (x >= 10) {

          clearInterval(timer);

        }
      } else {
        var y = document.getElementById("myNumber").stepDown();
        if (y <= -10) {

          clearInterval(timer);
        }
      }
    }
  </script>

  <p><strong>Your Score: <input type="number" id="myNumber"></strong>

</body>

</html>
```

In this code i want to store the value of number in a variable so that in the if-else statement i can compare the value of that number and with 10 and -10 and perform the action in the if-else statement.
I also want to print out that if the number becomes more than 10 it will print out you win and when the number become less than -10 then it will print out you loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could this `<p id="message"></p>` element next to your `input`, in your `if-else` statement add the following statements `var xVal=document.getElementById("myNumber").value;` and `if(xVal>=10){  clearInterval (timer); document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="You Win"}`, do the same work with other case. Check the following working solution:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>question 5</title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="b0" onclick="start()">Start Game</button>
<br>

<img src ="https://images.pexels.com/photos/45910/goldfish-carassius-fish-golden-45910.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940"  id ="fish" onclick="mySore()" height="200" width="200">

<script type="text/javascript">

    var image_tracker = 'happy'  ;
    var image = document.getElementById('fish');
    image.style.display = "none";
    function change() {
        if (image_tracker == 'happy'){

                image.src = 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/45910/goldfish-carassius-fish-golden-45910.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940';
                image_tracker = 'sad';
            }
            else{
                image.src = 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSCvJNQB6U62UvdD5oinU1hbpUWeUDAniae39-rlP6T7ONJARhQ';
                image_tracker = 'happy';
            }

    }
    var timer;
    function start(){
        image.style.display = "block";
        timer = setInterval ('change();',1600);
    }

    function stop() {
        clearInterval (timer);
    }


function mySore() {
    if( image_tracker == 'sad' ){
     var x =  document.getElementById("myNumber").stepUp();
     var xVal=document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
  
      if ( xVal >= 10){

        clearInterval (timer);
 document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="You Win";
image.style.display = "none";  document.getElementById("myNumber").disabled=true
      }
    }
    else{
     var y = document.getElementById("myNumber").stepDown();
     var yVal=document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
     
     if ( yVal < -10){
 document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="You lost";
 image.style.display = "none";  document.getElementById("myNumber").disabled=true
        clearInterval (timer);
      }
    }
}
</script>

<p><strong>Your Score: <input type="number" id="myNumber"></strong></p>
<p id="message"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thats really help full but after the process is finished the code increment the value of the number is still running. I want that the process of incrementing the value will also become constant and un-edittable means the text box must become constant.

Comment: i updated my answer to fit to your need by adding `image.style.display = "none";  document.getElementById("myNumber").disabled=true`

Comment: @AbhikYadav what's the problem? i think i solved your problem

Comment: Okk now u have editted and solved my problem nice work, really appreciate it man : )

Comment: @AbhikYadav in the top left of my answer there's two arrows (up and down) under that arrows there's a check mark click on it to accept my answer